# module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv

I have already installed opencv-contrib-python on pycharm but when I am running this code on pycharm:

```
import cv2

if __name__ == '__main__':

im=cv2.read('101_7.png', 0)
equ = cv2.GaussianBlur(im, (5, 5), 0)

cv2.imshow(equ)
```

The error I am getting is "module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'read'".
How to remove this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find the `read()` method in the [`opencv` docs](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html).

I think you need `imread()` for reading the image.

```
retval  =   cv.imread(  filename[, flags]   )
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV doesn't have `read`. It's `imread` for reading an image.